# How to convert my email ids into horizontal comma separated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a query where I am passing multiple values from my front end via `POP LOV (Oracle APEX 20.x)`

```
select column_value as val from table(apex_split(:MYIDS));
```

**It will be like this from above query**

```
select column_value as val from table('3456,89000,8976,5678');
```

**My Main query :**

```
SELECT email
FROM   student_details
WHERE  studid IN (SELECT column_value AS val
                  FROM   TABLE(apex_split(:MYIDS));
```

**My main query gives me below details as an output**

```
xyz@gmail.com
vbh@gmail.com
ghj@gmail.com
uj1@gmail.com
xy2@gmail.com
vb4@gmail.com
g2j@gmail.com
u8i@gmail.com
x3z@gmail.com
v9h@gmail.com
g00j@gmail.com
uj01@gmail.com
```

**But I want this above output as comma seperated in one line like below**

```
xyz@gmail.com,vbh@gmail.com,ghj@gmail.com,uj1@gmail.com,xy2@gmail.com,vb4@gmail.com,g2j@gmail.com,u8i@gmail.com,x3z@gmail.com,v9h@gmail.com,g00j@gmail.com,uj01@gmail.com
```

I want it by using `xmlelement cast` method as `listagg` as `some 4000 char length issue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly adjust your "main query":

```
SELECT listagg(email, ',') within group (order by null) 
FROM   student_details
WHERE  studid IN (SELECT column_value AS val
                  FROM   TABLE(apex_split(:MYIDS));
```

If you hit `listagg`'s 4000-character in length restriction, switch to `xmlagg`:

```
with your_main_query as
  (SELECT email 
   FROM   student_details
   WHERE  studid IN (SELECT column_value AS val
                     FROM   TABLE(apex_split(:MYIDS))
  )
SELECT RTRIM (
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, email || ',') ORDER BY NULL).EXTRACT (
               '//text()'),
            ',') AS result
    FROM your_main_query;
```

Comment: : Their is an issue with 4000 char length exceeded when listagg is used

Comment: If that's the case, use XMLAGG instead; see edited answer, please.